# Even Isometries in neutral Geometry

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Consider a Hilbert plane as in Hartshorne's 'Euclid and beyond' (axiomatic geometry), and its group of isometries f or 'rigid motion' generated by line reflections. Call f 'even' if it is the product of an even number of reflections, 'odd' otherwise.

Can f be even and odd at the same time?

In the standard euclidean or hyperbolic model space over the reals the answer is well known, but there are of course many more less familiar models in the non-complete case.

Let me add some remarks: the only complete (!) Hilbert planes are euclidean two space and the Poincare upper half plane (up to isometry). In both cases an isometry of the plane cannot be even and odd at the same time. Analytically even means oriented, odd means non-oriented. However, there are various rather unfamiliar examples of Hilbert planes in the non-complete case. Like 'semi elliptic planes' in the sense of Hartshorne's book, or archimedean examples but without limiting rays. That the real projective plane ('elliptic geometry') is non-orientable doesn't prove a thing but motivates the question. Another motivation the fact that simplifying products of reflections is a crucial step in Hilbert's theory of ends.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can hope more answers if you provide some online links with the involved definitions.

Comment: The definitions can be found in Hartshorne's book or in Hilbert's original work. The definitions are too elaborate to be repeated here.

Comment: Is it the same as what is defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms, assuming that there's a single plane and that everything lies in this plane?

Comment: I am confused: which axioms are you omitting? Are these the completeness axiom and the parallels postulate? Or is it also the Archimedean property?

Comment: The Axioms are essentially the same as in wikipedia, right, for details see Hartshorne's book. Geometry on Hilbert planes is neutral (absolut) geometry, so no parallel axiom and not necessarily Archimedean. There are cases like 'semi-elliptic planes' in the sense of Hartshorne. Something like: four reflections can always be reduced to two reflections may fail (?)

Comment: What's the research angle of this question? It looks like it belongs to that MathStackexchange rather than Mathoverflow.

Comment: But, in a Hilbert plane, one can still prove that every isometry is the product of at most 3 reflections: Let the isometry take three non-collinear points A, B, C to A', B', C'; then, composing with one reflection, if needed, take A' back to A, sending B', C' to B'', C''; then composing with a second reflection in a line through A, if needed, take B'' to B, sending C'' to C'''; then composing with a third reflection across the line AB, if needed, take C''' to C. The resulting composed isometry fixes A, B, and C, so it must be the identity (a conclusion that does not use any continuity axioms.)

Comment: @Bryant: your are correct. As I wrote, reflections generate the group of isometries. Consider a product of four reflections and use your algortihm. Is it possible that we end up with a single reflection? A product of three?

Comment: @Misha The question of how this is related to the classification of Hilbert planes is my research angle. I hope some expert in this axiom business will know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the answer to your question "Can $f$ be even and odd at the same time?" is *no*, but the argument that I have seems more complicated than I expected it to be.  The idea is synthetically to imitate the notion of a 'local orientation' and show that it has global coherence.  Here is an outline:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert plane and let $G$ be its group of isometries.  For each point $P$ in $H$ let $G_P\subset G$ be the subgroup consisting of those isometries of $H$ that fix $P$.

Let $R_P$ denote the set of rays in $H$ that emanate from $P$. Then $G_P$ acts transitively on $R_P$, and the stabilizer in $G_P$ of a ray $r \in R_P$ is a $2$-element subgroup consisting of the identity and the reflection in the line that is the union of $r$ and its opposite ray $-r$.

Now, let $C_P \subset G_P$ denote the set of elements that are either the identity or that fix no ray in $R_P$.  Then $C_P$ is a abelian subgroup of index $2$ in $G_P$, and its complement in $G_P$ is exactly the set of reflections in lines through $P$.  (It's easy to see that every element of $C_P$ is (not uniquely) the product of two reflections in lines through $P$.)

Now, for any two points $P$ and $Q$ in $H$, there is a canonical identification of $R_P$ with $R_Q$.  Namely, if $P=Q$, we take the identification to be the identity.  If $P\not=Q$, then consider the line $PQ$ and let $r\in R_P$ denote the ray emanating from $P$ that passes through $Q$.  This ray $r$ contains a unique ray $r'\in R_Q$ and we let $(-r)'=-r'\in R_Q$ denote the ray that corresponds to the opposite ray $-r\in R_P$.  For any other ray $s\in R_P$, we let $s'\in R_Q$ denote the ray that is on the same side of the line PQ as $s$ and for which the angle made by $r'$ and $s'$ is congruent to the angle made by $r$ and $s$.  Call this mapping $B_Q^P:R_P\to R_Q$.  Then $B_Q^P$ is a bijection and $B_P^Q$ is its inverse.

If $O$, $P$, and $Q$ are any three points, then the composition $B_P^OB_Q^PB_O^Q:R_O\to R_O$ is the action of an element of $C_O$ on $R_O$.  (It is the identity if $O$, $P$, and $Q$ are collinear.)
Meanwhile, if $\rho:H\to H$ is a reflection in a line, then $\rho$ induces a map  on rays $\rho'_P:R_P\to R_{\rho(P)}$, and $B^{\rho(P)}_P\circ\rho'_P:R_P\to R_P$ is induced by an element of $G_P$ that is *not* in $C_P$.

Finally, one can now divide the elements of $G$ into two classes:  The *even* elements $f$ are the isometries such that $B^{f(P)}_P\circ f'_P:R_P\to R_P$
is induced by an element of $C_P$.  (This condition turns out to be independent of $P$.)  These form a subgroup $G_0\subset G$.  The *odd* elements, which contain all the reflections in lines, are what is left.  Moreover, it now follows that $G_0$ consists of products of an even number of line reflections, while its complement consists of all of the products of an odd number of line reflections.

The proofs of all the claims made in this outline (and they do require proof) are straightforward, though tedious.

Comment: @Bryant Thank you for your answer. I tried something similar but trying to prove what I think you call 'indepence of p', I ended up with the original problem. I will give it a second thought, though. In the real projective plane with homogeneous coordinates x,y,z, if you think of (x,y,z)->(-x,y,z) as the reflection along x=0, then the product of the three reflections along the three axis is the identity, so 'odd is even'. This is not a Hilbert plane but some axioms still make sense.

Comment: @MarcGonsevic:  Certainly, the argument would not work for the projective plane.  One cannot even define $R_P$ or the bijection $B^P_Q$ for the projective plane since lines have no sides, and there is no betweenness relation that satisfies the betweenness axioms, which is essential to the arguments.  My argument for the independence of $P$ claimed in the penultimate paragraph needs the result that the composition $B^O_PB^P_QB^Q_O$ belongs to $C_O$.  (It is not generally the identity, unless the plane satisfies the parallel postulate.)

Comment: Ok, thank you again. It was pointed out to me that I'm precisely looking at 'Axiom P' from Bachmann's 'Geometrie aus dem Speigelungsbegriff' from 1959. Bachmann cooks it down to the question of the existence of three reflections giving the identity when multiplied, just as in the P2 example. This is impossible in Hilbert planes leading to the answer you already gave.

Comment: I do not see how to show that $B_P^O B_Q^P B_O^Q$ is an element of $C_O$? I observe that $B_Q^P$ is actually induced by an isometry: Let $\ell$ be the perpendicular on $PQ$ in $P$ and $m$ the bisector of the segment from $P$ to $Q$; then first reflecting in $\ell$ and then in $m$ gives the map $B_Q^P$ on the rays. So $B_P^O B_Q^P B_O^Q$ is a product of six reflections and fixes $O$; why can't it be a reflection?

Comment: @FriederLadisch:  You ask a good question, as this is not obvious.  I remember that that argument was tedious, but straightforward.  One has to prove that, if $B^O_PB^P_QB^Q_O$ fixes a ray, then it must be the identity, so one assumes that it fixes a ray and uses that ray to show that it fixes all the rays.  I don't remember the argument now (that was 5 years ago), but I'll try to reconstruct it.

Comment: Yes, I know that I'm late to the party. I was thinking about exactly the same question as OP and found this. I think I see now how to answer the original question using arguments from Bachmann's book as suggested by @MarcGonsevic above (Satz 11, 15 and 16 in §3 are particular relevant), but to me this looks rather different from your argument. So don't put too much time in reconstructing the argument...